# asp:HyperLink is not rendered on browser

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010, dom, asp.net-webcontrol

Hello guys I'm stuck with this weird problem ,`asp:HyperLink` control is not being rendered inside browser,it does not even exists in the final HTML sent to the browser.

**Home.aspx Asp.net Markup**

```
<div class="LoginBox">
    <div id="LoginViewBox" runat="server">
          <asp:HyperLink ID="linkLogout" runat="server" OnClick="LogOut"></asp:HyperLink>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Home.aspx in the browser**

```
<div class="LoginBox">
  <div id="ctl00_HeadHolder_LoginViewBox">&nbsp;Welcome&nbsp;owaisBhai&nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

**Home.Aspx.Cs**

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(!IsPostBack)
       {
           LoginBoxManager.PopulateLoginBox(ref LoginViewBox, ref linkLogout);
       }
    }
```

**LoginBoxManager.cs**

```
    public static class LoginBoxManager
{
    public static void PopulateLoginBox(ref HtmlGenericControl loginViewBox, ref HyperLink linkLogout)
    {
        string LogInUrl = "Login.aspx";
        string WelcomeGuest = String.Format("&nbsp;Welcome Guest&nbsp;<a href='{0}'>[LogIn]</a>", LogInUrl);
        string WelcomeUser = "";

        if (HttpContext.Current.Session.Count == 0)
        {
            //user not authenticated
            loginViewBox.InnerHtml = WelcomeGuest;
        }
        else
        {
            //user authenticated
            WelcomeUser = 
            String.Format("&nbsp;Welcome&nbsp; {0}&nbsp;"
                                ,SmartSession<User>.LiveSession.UserName);
            loginViewBox.InnerHtml = WelcomeUser;
            linkLogout.Text = "[LogOut]";
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S:** I think I have well explained the situation let me know of any details.

Comment: I do add text in asp:HyperLink when user is authenticated check the `LoginBoxManager.cs` else condition

Comment: The next think that you can check is if you have add the href, its a hyper link after all...

Comment: I added in Markup `NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx"` ,but browser didnt showed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is replacing the asp:HyperLink with text. The problem line is this line:

```
loginViewBox.InnerHtml = WelcomeGuest;
```

By setting the InnerHtml property, you are replacing the HTML that will appear in your LoginViewBox div.

Instead of this approach, i would recommend adding a label into the div. This would give you a final structure of:

```
<div id="LoginViewBox">
      <asp:Label ID="LoginLabel" runat="server"/>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="linkLogout" runat="server" OnClick="LogOut"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
```

(it's been a while since I've done straight ASP.NET, so there might be more required attributes for the label control).

Comment: Wow Jeff Siver your answer was a SilverBullet it worked and I'm thinking now what a stupid mistake I made :)

Comment: `<asp:Panel>` doesn't have an innerHtml attribute, but `<div>` does? That's interesting. Doesn't the `<div>` need a `runat="server"` attribute for it to be referenced in the code-behind?

Comment: If I remember correctly, my recommendation meant removing the code behind that updated LoginViewBox which is why I didn't have the runat="server" tag. And the asp:Panel control doesn't have an innerHtml attribute because it has a Controls collection which provides better support for these types of operations.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be setting the `linkLogout.NavigateUrl` property anywhere.  Try setting that.

Comment: I have just added in Markup NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" ,but browser didnt showed it.

Comment: Thank for looking into the problem :) ,+1 for that